# Async operations with Spray, Akka, and actorSelection

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I keep running into the same design problem using spray, which is how to find the original context of the Spray http request for a request, after doing some asynchronous (tell) operations in Akka.

I'm using Net-a-Porter [actor per request model](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request). It creates a child actor which I specify to handle each request, which is incapsulated by another actor which holds the correct request context.

Let let's call my actor ActorA, which has this receive method on it:

```
def receive: Receive = {
 case v : InputJson =>
   val id = createId
   val redisList = context.actorOf(Props[RedisListActor])
   // At this point, sender is the 'per-request' actor created, which has the HTTP context of the Spray request.
   redisList ! ListRequest(id, sender.path.toStringWithoutAddress, v)
```

This is adding input to a job queue on redis, which is consumed on another server. When this job is completed, the other server adds the result to a Redis PubSub queue which we are subscribed to. When an item comes into this queue, it alerts my ActorA (using context.actorOf).

```
case kr : KubernetesReply =>
  context.system.actorSelection(kr.actorPath) ! TaskResponse("Success", kr.payload, kr.id)
```

You can see that I am trying to find the original sender through using it's actorPath, but upon the KubernetesReply, I find that path is deadLetters (even though I have not explicitly killed the request actor). I've confirmed it's the correct path (i.e. I can send back the task response from the InputJson handler).

What's the correct pattern for this? How can I find my original actor, and why has it disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `ActorRef` directly in the `ListRequest` message.

```
case class ListRequest(id: YourIdType, requestActor: ActorRef, json: InputJson)

def receive: Receive = {
  case v : InputJson =>
    val id = createId
    val redisList = context.actorOf(Props[RedisListActor])
    redisList ! ListRequest(id, sender, v)
  case kr : KubernetesReply =>
    kr.requestActor ! TaskResponse("Success", kr.payload, kr.id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Unfortunately ListRequest isn't replying the KubernetesReply; this happens from a separate PubSub actor which is always listening for messages. Thus, the actor sending KubernetesReply has no idea of the original sender of InputJson. The only way I could think to pass the actor's reference was through passing its name to and from Redis (or having some kind of mutable lookup table with ids and actorRefs, but I'd rather avoid that..)

Comment: @Leo Maybe this could help: [Serializing ActorRefs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html#Serializing%20ActorRefs)